# How to navigate to seperate Fragments when clicked on different Tabs in TabLayout in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

I have three Tabs [Easy,Medium and Hard] and I want to open three different Fragments for each Tab or the default Tab for Easy Fragment data and two more Fragments for for Medium and Hard. So, I have finished intergating the Tabs using ViewPager 2 and TabLayout but I am not able to understand how to can I navigate to diffrent fragments here. Note, I know how to create a Navigation on Nav Graph, I am just not sure how to navigate to various Fragments on Tab clicks. Following is my Fragment code.

Flashcards.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.visuallithuanian.R
import com.example.visuallithuanian.adapter.FlashcardsAdapter
import com.example.visuallithuanian.data.FlashCardInfo
import com.example.visuallithuanian.ui.activities.FirstScreen
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint


@AndroidEntryPoint
class FlashCards : Fragment() {

    lateinit var bottomNav:BottomNavigationView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_flash_cards,
container, false)

        //Taking the bOTTOMNavigation view instance from Activity into Fragment
        bottomNav = (activity as?
FirstScreen)?.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView)!!
        bottomNav.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        val back_icon = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.back_icon)
        val recyclerViewCards1 =
view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerViewFlashcards)

        recyclerViewCards1.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(),
            R.id.nav_host_fragment
        )

        val flashCardList = generateFlashCards()
        val adapter = FlashcardsAdapter(flashCardList,navController)
        recyclerViewCards1.adapter = adapter


        // setting up listener
        back_icon.setOnClickListener {
            activity?.onBackPressed()
        }

        return view
    }

    private fun generateFlashCards():List<FlashCardInfo> {
        return listOf(
            FlashCardInfo(R.drawable.talking,"Daily Conversation",""),
            FlashCardInfo(R.drawable.doctorvisit,"Questions and Pronouns",""),
            FlashCardInfo(R.drawable.food,"Food",""),
            FlashCardInfo(R.drawable.relatives,"Relatives",""),
            FlashCardInfo(R.drawable.clothing,"Clothing",""),
            FlashCardInfo(R.drawable.village,"Towns and Villages",""),
            FlashCardInfo(R.drawable.nature,"Nature",""),
            FlashCardInfo(R.drawable.verbs,"Popular Verbs",""),
        )

    }


}
```

This is my Adapter class FlashcardsAdapter.kt

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.visuallithuanian.data.FlashCardInfo
import com.example.visuallithuanian.ui.activities.fragments.FlashCardsDirections


class FlashcardsAdapter(private val imageList: List<FlashCardInfo>
,  private val navController: NavController
) :RecyclerView.Adapter<FlashcardsAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val imageViewFlashcards =
itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.id.imageViewFlashcards)
        val textViewFlashcards =
itemView.findViewById<TextView>(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.id.textflashCardName)
       // val textViewFlashcardsLithuanian =
itemView.findViewById<TextView>(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.id.textflashCardLithuanian)

        val cardviewFlashcard =
itemView.findViewById<CardView>(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.id.cardFlashCards)

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int):
ViewHolder {
        val view =
LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.layout.item_flashcards,
parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current_item = imageList[position]

        holder.imageViewFlashcards.setImageResource(current_item.imageId)
        holder.textViewFlashcards.text = current_item.name
    //    holder.textViewFlashcardsLithuanian.text = current_item.translation

        holder.cardviewFlashcard.setOnClickListener {
            val action = when(position){
                    1
->FlashCardsDirections.actionFlashCardsToQuestionsFragment()

                else -> return@setOnClickListener
            }
            action.let {
                navController.navigate(it)
            }

        }


    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return imageList.size
    }
}
```

So, How can I add functionality to navigate to various Fragments on Tab clicks?